# Pass string straight to angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand how to work with directives in Angular. In the examples on [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org/), values are set in the scope in JavaScript, and then that scope is referenced when matching a directive.

Template:

```
  <my-customer info="naomi"></my-customer>
```

Scope:

```
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.naomi = { name: 'Cat', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.igor = { name: 'Dog', address: '123 Somewhere' };
  })
```

Template:

```
Name: {{customerInfo.name}} Address: {{customerInfo.address}}
```

I would like to pass the attribute, straight from the template. So in this example I would like to write a template that outputs:

```
Name: Naomi
```

Without going through a scope.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using the `attrs` argument of the [linking function](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
module.directive('name', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.info);
      // <- 'naomi'
    }
  }
});
```

Then in markup:

```
<name info='naomi'></name>
```

[See a live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Bx55YQvjrofbNJsad6W?p=preview)

Comment: cool, how do I use it with the template-attribute?       template: 'Name: {{attrs.info}}' doesn't work

Comment: when should I run the $eval? in the link?