# Pass a string into an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass a string into an angular directive,

```
<person first-name="Don" last-name="Dood"></person>
<person first-name="James" last-name="Jawalla"></person>
```

and get this result HTML:

```
<p>Don Dood</p>
<p>James Jawalla</p>
```

Here is what I currently have.

**Directive**:

```
.directive('person', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      firstName: '@',
      lastName: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'person-template.html'
  }
});
```

**person-template.html**

```
<p>{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}</p>
```

However there are no values appearing for firstName or lastName. What am I missing?

It's a simple question, so I'm surprised there is no good answer on SO. Closest I found was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521154/pass-string-straight-to-angular-directive), but it does not say how to show a string in HTML.

Comment: the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/

Comment: use '=' instead of '@'

Comment: @pankajparkar, you mean like what I'm currently doing?

Comment: @DonnyP Yes you're right, it will do two way binding

Comment: @DonnyP You may now freely delete your question....

Comment: '@' is the correct scope binding to use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'@' is the correct scope binding to use here as strings are being passed to the directive.

I believe you're missing a restrict:'E' in your DDO, but other than that your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer - can you make a note in your answer that '@' is the correct symbol to use when passing strings in a directive? People are going to get confused when they see the other comments on this page that suggest using two-way data binding to other scope objects.

Comment: No. It's not correct. By default restrict is on 'EA' so the OP already stated the problem was somewhere else, so this is not doing anything...

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal, the default restrict for 1.3+ is EA. For versions, 1.2 and below, the default restrict is 'A'.  You should admit to the OP that you were wrong, and move on...

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, this code works. I had a bug elsewhere in my code that was making this seem not to work. Can't delete since it already has an answer.

A reminder: If you are passing a string as an attribute use the `@` sign (as I do in the question). If you passing an object, variable, etc and you want it to be two-way binded, then use the `=` sign.

Comment: You're wrong. Though you can delete your answer and question, I'll delete my answer...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I believe your answer should up voted. because you replied as soon as question has been asked.

Comment: Thanks. But that's not what I'm here for. Just helping people in right way around...

Comment: I'm sorry @BhojendraNepal, but you made a suggestion to use two-way data binding with `=`.  The question was to pass a string into the directive.  For that you should use `@`, so your answer is wrong (although I appreciate the effort, I can't mark it as correct). Here is a reference to the SO question that states this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope.